# Force routing without context

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation

am working on chat app , now am stuck on the idea of , if one of the two users left the page i wanna force the other user also to leave the page and back to home screen , i tried many things , boolean , conditions , will pop , nothing work  , how can i implement a function to do this job , am using flutter , much appreciate .

i tried using boolean to set a condition to check if user exist , i tried to use will pop , i saw a couple of articles bout it , i even tried to set timer to force the second user to leave , but nothing happened , the problem is there's no action from the other user that make him leave the page , with or without on press , while the first user did the action and pressed the button to leave .

this is the button in the home page who do logic to match through firebase

child: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () async {
var res = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
.doc(
'match/$_currentValue1$_currentValue2$_currentThumbValue')
.get();
var value = res.exists;
print('RESULT = $value');

```
                        /// If Code Is Not Exist
                        try {
                          if (value == false) {
                            /// Create Code In Match Document
                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('match')
                                .doc('$_currentValue1$_currentValue2$_currentThumbValue')
                                .set({
                              'user1Id': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                              'user1Name': userInfo['displayName'] ?? 'username',
                              'user2Id': '',
                              'user2Name': '',
                            });
                            print('Match Created By ${userInfo['displayName']}');

                            /// Create Code Reference In Real Time
                            await codeRef.set({
                              'code': '$_currentValue1$_currentValue2$_currentThumbValue',
                              'user1Id': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                              'user1Name': userInfo['displayName'] ?? 'username',
                              'user2Id': '',
                              'user2Name': '',
                            });

                            /// Timer To Delete Code If No Match Found
                            var counter = 10;
                            Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                (timer) async {
                              setState(() {
                                isMatchVisible = false;
                              });
                              print(timer.tick);
                              print('Data Value During Countdown : $value');
                              counter--;

                              /// Check If User2 Exist Im Match Document
                              DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection('match')
                                      .doc('$_currentValue1$_currentValue2$_currentThumbValue')
                                      .get();

                              ///
                              if (documentSnapshot.get('user2Id') != '') {
                                timer.cancel();

                                var goToPageUser1 = 2;
                                Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                    (timer) async {
                                  goToPageUser1--;
                                  if (goToPageUser1 == 0) {
                                    timer.cancel();

                                    /// Go To Chat Screen
                                    await Get.toNamed(
                                      '/ChatScreen',
                                      arguments:
                                          '$_currentValue1$_currentValue2$_currentThumbValue',
                                      parameters: {
                                        'name1': userInfo['displayName'],
                                        'Id1': user!.uid,
                                      },
                                      preventDuplicates: false,
                                    );
                                  }
                                });
                              } else {
                                if (counter == 0) {
                                  var failCounter = 5;
                                  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                      (timer) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      showFailResult = true;
                                    });
                                    failCounter--;
                                    if (failCounter == 0) {
                                      timer.cancel();
                                      setState(() {
                                        showFailResult = false;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  });

                                  /// Delete Code From Match Collection
                                  DocumentReference docCode = FirebaseFirestore
                                      .instance
                                      .collection('match')
                                      .doc(
                                          '${_currentValue1.toString()}${_currentValue2.toString()}${_currentThumbValue.toString()}');
                                  await docCode
                                      .delete()
                                      .then((value) =>
                                          print('Match Code Deleted'))
                                      .catchError((error) => print(
                                          "Failed To Delete Match Code: $error"));

                                  /// Delete Room From Real Time
                                  await codeRef.remove();

                                  print('Cancel timer');
                                  timer.cancel();
                                  setState(() {
                                    value = false;
                                    isMatchVisible = true;
                                    print(
                                        'Data Value After Countdown : $value');
                                  });
                                }
                              }
                            });

                            /// If Code Is Exist
                          } else if (value == true) {
                            /// Update Match Document For User1 AND User2
                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('match')
                                .doc(
                                  '${_currentValue1.toString()}${_currentValue2.toString()}${_currentThumbValue.toString()}',
                                )
                                .update({
                              'user2Id':
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                              'user2Name':
                                  userInfo['displayName'] ?? 'username',
                            });

                            /// Update Match Code In Real Time
                            await codeRef.update({
                              'user2Id':
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                              'user2Name':
                                  userInfo['displayName'] ?? 'username',
                            });

                            var goToPageUser2 = 2;
                            Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                (timer) async {
                              goToPageUser2--;
                              if (goToPageUser2 == 0) {
                                timer.cancel();

                                /// Go To Chat Screen
                                await Get.toNamed(
                                  '/ChatScreen',
                                  arguments:
                                      '$_currentValue1$_currentValue2$_currentThumbValue',
                                  parameters: {
                                    'name2': userInfo['displayName'],
                                    'Id2': user!.uid,
                                  },
                                  preventDuplicates: false,
                                );
                              }
                            });
                          }
                        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                          showSnackBar(context, e.message!);
                        }
                      },
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Match'.tr,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written to do this.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. There are a lot of ways to do this. It depends on what state management you're using, what routing you're using etc...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.